# Upgrade to Chrome 51 freezes DOM manipulation

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a `select2` field that loads its content via AJAX after some user actions. This was working well with all browsers. Last week, after Google release Google Chrome 51, the page freezes when calling `.html(...)` to set the content of the dropdown. I found that the page stays frozen for about 2 minutes. The content of the dropdown is not very complex and it works smoothly in all other browsers.

Is there any important change in Chrome 51 that would break jquery DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

If you are using Firebug Firefox, you'll notice the problem from time loading of JavaScript files so you have to make JavaScript files call firstly by put them inside main page or before the code script .
or you can use `getscript()` method .